# Boost::interprocess message queue compatible with windows?

Tags: c++, boost-interprocess

Windows 10

MSCV 19.25.28614.0

Boost 1.72.0

While attempting to initalise a basic message queue taken from sample code in the docs:

```
 message_queue mq
        (create_only               //only create   
            , "message_queue"           //name   
            , 100                       //max message number   
            , sizeof(int)               //max message size   
        );
```

I get a run time error about a unhandled exception `boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception` in the function `bool shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create` in `shared_memory_object.hpp`. Has anyone experienced this error on Windows and if so do you have any advice on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. Make sure you add:

```
message_queue::remove("message_queue");
```

Before you attempt to create one:

```
 message_queue mq
        (create_only               //only create   
            , "message_queue"           //name   
            , 100                       //max message number   
            , sizeof(int)               //max message size   
        );
```